# Can we access WCF service over https using Jquery $.ajax() call in cross domain?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, https, cross-domain

I have added SSL for both applications.

Assume `https:// www.a.com` and `https:// www.b.com`. 
`https:// www.a.com` is accessing the *wcf* service from `https:// www.b.com` through `$.ajax()` call. 
I am also using **jsonp** to this functionality. When these application are not *https* it works fine. But the `$.ajax()` call fails when I make it *https*. It giving **"Internel server error"** in *firebug* on this `$.ajax()` call.

Can we do such thing in secure mode?

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing on the server side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Suggestion 1:

Using [CORS(Cross Orignin resource sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

During the *preflight request*,

you should see the following two headers:

> - Access-Control-Request-Method
> - Access-Control-Request-Headers

These request headers are asking the server for permissions to make the actual request.

Your *preflight response needs to acknowledge these headers* in order for the *actual request to work*.

For example, suppose the browser makes a request with the following headers:

> - Origin: http://yourdomain.com
> - Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> - Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Custom-Header

Your server should then respond with the following headers:

> - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com
> - Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
> - Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
>     X-Custom-Header

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689332/730807)

### Suggestion 2:

Using [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and Intermediate page:

- create a intermediate page which makes http request to https page and return JSON-P result
- If the intermediate page is in **same domain** then use it *directly* else make *cross domain ajax request* and use *JSON-P*

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618114/730807)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd be a heck of a lot better off just reading/writing JSON data over your encrypted (https) connection.  Let WCF handle whatever you want at the endpoints, but communicate with simple JSON messages.  IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

We can access WCF service over https using jquery ajax call in cross domain, But we get security alert when such call is raised.

As per [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) we can access if it is same domain and same protocol.

For details please see [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Try adding CORS to the host server, then you should get it working

Comment: CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) is supported in most of the modern browsers so you could definetly give it a try.In simple words Your server has to retrun in respose header Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https:// www.a.com To know how more visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing special about https vs http as far as jsonp requests are concerned. An internal server error usually indicates that the web server threw an exception. What is the status code (500)?

If it is a 500, I would see if you can identify any differences in the requests using chrome's debugger or firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a service on the host server that accepts the request from the client. The service would then make the cross-domain request and send the data back to the client. That way you don't have to change any configuration.