# backbone.js and CORS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cors

I have been able to implement a CORS response with a `fetch()`.

However, when I look to `save()` a model using `PUT` have been unable to implement this.  The response which comes back is

```
OPTIONS http://[external domain] 501 (Not Implemented)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[external domain]. Origin http://127.0.0.1:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Can anyone give me an example of how to change backbone sync to implement this? or is this even possible?

Comment: It looks like the server needs CORS support added not backbone.

Comment: Server has cors support hence the fetch request works

Comment: It is still a server issue. `501 Not Implemented: The server either does not recognise the request method, or it lacks the ability to fulfill the request.` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Comment: What jquery version are you using?

Comment: Also showing some headers would be useful.

Comment: jquery 1.7.1.  Re the server, I have added `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT` as well as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: If you inspect the response headers to the OPTIONS request those headers are present?

Comment: You can test it with `curl -v -X options http://127.0.0.1:8888/path`

Comment: @Joe, Please have a look at my answer to a related post on a similar issue. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035812/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-to-an-api-using-cors-and-backbonejs/10038912#10038912>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do any action other than a `GET` using CORS you have to go through the pre-flight process as outlined in this question/answer: [CORS - How do 'preflight' an httprequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest) and also on this blog post: http://avalanche123.com/blog/2011/10/10/cross-domain-javascript-lessons-learned/

You have to make some extra steps beyond the easy GET CORS workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/cross-domain-ajax/). It provides a simple interface for enabling backwards compatible CORS. I don't have any sample for how to implement Backbone.sync, but it should be pretty straight forward.

Hope this helps!