# How to make an ajax request to an API using CORS and backbonejs

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, cross-domain, cors

I'm working on a backbone.js project and I'm calling my github repo. I have the my Collections and Models bootloaded so they exist once my page is built, but when I call model.fetch() I get this message: (replace :username with a username)

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.github.com/users/:username.
Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've read a few messages [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486213/backbone-js-and-cross-domain-scripting), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659283/backbone-js-fetch-with-parameters), they mention modifying the backbone.sync function but I'm not entirely sure how. Here is my code so far (this is in my Backbone.Router):

```
userDetails: function(id) {
    console.log('Loading: userDetails');
    var User = Users.get(id);
    User.fetch({dataType: "jsonp"});
    console.log(User);
    userView = new UserView({
        model: User
    });
    userView.render();
},
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also, duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Not Allowed by Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327218/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by)

Comment: api.github.com does support jsonp. In jQuery set your URL to include `callback=?` and it'll work just fine. So make your URL be `api.github.com/users/toddself?callback=?` and jQuery will handle the jsonp call and provide data to your success function as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CORS is enabled on the backend. The jQuery underpinnings knows when it's make a cross-origin request and modifies it accordingly.  The problem is the server, in this case, `api.github.com` does not allow CORS requests.

The server would have to respond with (at minumum):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (or the host in which your page is being served)`

Since you likely do not own github, you'll have to either write a server-side proxy OR see if github can provide you with a JSONP call (which jQuery is happy to make for you as well).

[MDN Documentation on Access-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control)

---

**EDIT**

That being said, if you need to modify a request made by jQuery through backbone, there is no need to override the `sync` method.  Use [jQuery's `$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method to add any additional headers, set types, etc.  Just make sure you run the `$.ajaxSetup` method in the same context or closure as the `.save()`, `.fetch()` or `.destroy()` is going to run or you won't get the work being performed in `$.ajaxSetup`

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar problem recently and ended up using the **mod_proxy**.
Please refer to: http://blog.lakmali.com/2010/11/apache-proxy-configuration-and-load.html
This blog post is pretty clear and straight forward to follow.

**mod_proxy** supports "https" too, I haven't tried it yet myself, however! 
Please google more to read about Proxy-choices such as mod_proxy, mod_jk etc.

By going with mod_proxy, we no longer have to make any Cross-Domain calls. Hence,  there was no need to worry about IE8/IE9's **XDomainRequest** hack for performing Cross-Domain requests. [**Note**: Before using *mod_proxy*, We were trying to over-ride the Backbone.sync to make explicit calls to XDomainRequest instead of jQuery's *ajax* in order to take care of CORS issues on IE9!]