# Backone, Ajax and Restful JSON Service

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, jsonp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - How to remove cross domain limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299438/jquery-how-to-remove-cross-domain-limitation)

I'm currently developing a single-page-application based on Backbone.js.
I'm also having a remote RESTful-Service which answeres with JSON-Results (this service can't be changed..).

Obviously the problem is that I'm not able to consume the rest-service in my SPA because it does not support JSONP.

The question that I'm having is: Does this mean that there is no way that my SPA can use the restful service unless it changes its answere-format to JSONP?? Or is there some kind of workaround that I did not find yet.

Thank you

EDIT:
I found a very interesting post that covers my questions.

[jQuery - How to remove cross domain limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299438/jquery-how-to-remove-cross-domain-limitation)

Comment: Do you mean to say the single-page application is hosted on a different server than your REST service?

Comment: You could proxy the REST service through your own server.

Comment: yes the spa is hostet on a different server.
I actually don't want to proxy the service because that would cause a lack of performance..

Comment: @user1727072 are you sure it would cause a lack of performance? I've written several apps that use third party data services proxied through my own backend, and they've never had noticeable issues with latency due to this...

Comment: +1 on using proxy. Please see my response to a related(kind of IE-specific) question, but it solves a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035812/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-to-an-api-using-cors-and-backbonejs/10038912#10038912