# How to get full request header to take effect in Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

So I have the following code snippet for carrying out a get request authenticated with a token to an API:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "<API URL>",
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {"X-Api-Key": "<API Key>"}
});
</script>
```

The issue is that the API doesn't seem to actually receive the API key data. I get back a MissingAuthenticationTokenException.

Moreover, when I look at the raw request data in the browser I see:

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-api-key
```

You'll notice it lists x-api-key but doesn't seem to show any value assigned to it.

In contrast, on the command line I make successful GET calls with the following command:

```
curl -X GET -H 'X-Api-Key: <API KEY>' '<API URL>'
```

How can I alter my script to correctly pass the header data to the API?

Comment: If you `console.log()` the `API key` value within the scope of the `ajax` call, is the expected value output to the console? We may need to see more code.

Comment: Alright, how can I console.log in this context? The relevant data is in an anonymous map where we can't put functions.

Comment: If this is a cross domain request then issue is CORS related. No custom headers get sent with OPTIONs preflight request. Probably need to set up a proxy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920422/how-to-handle-custom-headers-with-cors-pre-flight-request-ajax-codeigniter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994507/how-do-you-send-a-custom-header-in-a-cross-domain-cors-xmlhttprequest

Comment: If `ajax` hasn't got access to the value, it can't send it in the header, so, try console.logging the value within the same scope as the `ajax` call to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Oh, it's a string literal so I guarantee it's got access.

Comment: Have you tried using [`beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of `headers`? Does that work?