# How to configure CORS in APIMan

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, keycloak, apiman

I'm new on apiman, and I'm trying to use some API calls with Jquery. But unfortunately I got this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://apigtw.url/apiman-gateway///1.0/?apikey=9999999-8888-6666-33333-968a712ce68b.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://myapp.local' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 500.

So, I'm using some policies, such as:

**Keycloak Authorization Policy:**

```
Require OAuth: true
Require Transport Security: true
Blacklist Unsafe Tokens: false
Realm: https://sso.local/auth/realms/test-realm
Keycloak Realm Certificate: <keycloak key certificate>
Forward Realm Roles? true
```

**Authorization Policy Configuration:**

```
Path: .*
Verb: *
Required Role: my-role
```

Did I miss something on apiman configuration?

I believe I should add [CORs](http://www.apiman.io/blog/security/plugin/policy/cors/1.2.x/2016/01/22/cors-redux.html), but I don't know if it is necessary. I tried to use this but the error still occurs.

Please, need help

Does anyone know how to configure APIMan CORs?

**Edit:**

It seems this is was solved in [issue 516](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/APIMAN-516), but still occurs with me. I'm using version 1.2.3 of APIMan

Here is the Response Headers:

```
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 28 Dec 2016 13:54:08 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Gateway-Error:API not public.
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
```

and

Here is the Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, x-api-key
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host: apiman.url
Origin:http://192.168.56.22:8080
Referer:http://192.168.56.22:8080/app
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 ...
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
```

And here is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://apiman.url/apiman-gateway/<org>/<api>/1.0/<method>?apikey=xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Accept' : 'application/json',
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token
  },
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log('header1', data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: Thanks! that link has a similiar content and can help me. But I believe I can add more info with this link ['CORS? Of Course!'](http://www.apiman.io/blog/security/plugin/policy/cors/1.2.x/2016/01/22/cors-redux.html).

Comment: Maybe the question is too generic. I'll change this

Answer (score 2):

Have you ensured that the CORS policy is *before* the Keycloak policy in the policy chain? That will ensure CORS is serviced first.

i.e. CORS Policy -> Keycloak Policy -> Authorization Policy

NB: If you're using the CORS policy then you should probably pass your API key as a query parameter because browsers do not pass custom headers during preflight request (that it performs on your behalf).

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997235/2766538

Comment: Thanks @Marc!

This is only policy that I got. Btw, I don't if this can be useful, but I put this policy on my plans between my client and API.

Comment: For now, I just remove the keycloak and authorization policies. For now i'm trying to understand why the request is not considering my request headers

Comment: From the edit you provided - the error indicates that you're not using the correct URL to access the API. You should be using the URL provided from the client tab - you seem to be attempting to access it directly.

Comment: I Fix it! It is because I sent apikey as query parameter in the first attempt.
Soory for that

Comment: I used this same url on browser and works fine. I just removed the keycloak policies for while