# Postman mock service not accepting preflight request

Tags: cors, postman, axios, preflight

Using the Postman Pro API, i have created a Postman mock for my collection.

I have created an example response for GET `/auth/jwt/login` which returns an example JWT token.

I have used the mock successfully via postman (including the `x-api-key` header) but when i try and use this in the browser, adding the header into my request (using axios), Postman responds to the preflight OPTIONS request with

`` {"error":{"name":"invalidCredentialsError","message":"Please provide the required `x-api-key` authentication header."}} ``

as expected the browser is stripping the x-api-key header (as per CORS spec) see: [How do you send a custom header in a cross-domain (CORS) XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994507/how-do-you-send-a-custom-header-in-a-cross-domain-cors-xmlhttprequest)

So how do i use the Postman mock servers from my application while in development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is missing the `x-api-key` in the preflight `OPTIONS` request. Can you inspect the `OPTIONS` request and see if the `x-api-key` header is being passed?

If the `x-api-key` is being passed then check if the response is sending a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. If it is not then your CORS request will not work. The mock server needs to allow this and AFAIK this will be rolled out to all users soon.

Comment: I also emailed  help@getpostman.com and got the following response. ```We're aware of this, and will be rolling out support for CORS soon, hopefully within a week. Stay tuned to https://twitter.com/postmanclient for updates``` So looks like an issue on the Postman side not allowing for preflight.

Comment: @Kieran - You should be able to use it now. Works for me.