# syntax difference between PUT and POST method

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, httprequest, put

I am writing a restful API and try to use all available http method but have a problem with PUT method.

When I send http request whith put method, I have "400 Bad request" error.
If I use POST method, I have no problem.

Here is my http PUT request :

```
Remote Address:::1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/adminRight
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:400 Mauvaise Requête

Request Headersview parsed
PUT /adminRight HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: JSESSIONID=41D1CCDF94D3150F0FCA3754E347A4AD

Request Payload
typeList=1&id=2&nom=labelViewerAvance

Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 400 Mauvaise Requête
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 984
Date: Fri, 30 May 2014 12:55:32 GMT
Connection: close
```

And here my http POST request :

```
Remote Address:::1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/adminRight
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headersview parsed
POST /adminRight HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: JSESSIONID=41D1CCDF94D3150F0FCA3754E347A4AD

Request Payload
typeList=1&id=2&nom=labelViewerAvance

Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Date: Fri, 30 May 2014 13:09:03 GMT
```

What is the difference between PUT and POST syntax? Or maybe, is it one special configuration in my web.xml?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit with new information :**

My requests are mapped in java with these two methods :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminRight", 
                method = RequestMethod.PUT
                )
     @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<String> updateListRights(@RequestParam(value = "typeList") String typeList,
                @RequestParam(value = "id") String idList,
                @RequestParam(value = "nom") String nomList)
        {
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminRight", 
                method = RequestMethod.POST
                )
     @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<String> addNewListRights(@RequestParam(value = "typeList") String typeList,
                @RequestParam(value = "id") String idList,
                @RequestParam(value = "nom") String nomList)

        {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1` is just a HTTP connector. Behind that connector there is a web server, for example [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/coyote.html). You have to look up the manual of that server and check how you can allow a HTTP method. By [Tomcat there is a server.xml file](http://www.techstacks.com/howto/disable-http-methods-in-tomcat.html), in that there is something like this:

```
// Sample Security Constraint
 <security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name><strong>restricted methods</strong></web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <http-method>PUT</http-method>
  <http-method>POST</http-method>
  <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
  <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
  <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint />
 </security-constraint>
```

You should add PUT and DELETE to that list. If your REST clients are running in browsers and they are served under a different domain, then you have to enable the OPTIONS method either (for [CORS preflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest) requests), and add [CORS allow headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) as well. By serving browsers you have to add [some HTTP response headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) as well and [set them properly](https://blog.veracode.com/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/) to prevent [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Another security concern that you should [hide the version number](http://securitythoughts.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-modify-apache-coyote1-1-banner/) of the coyote connector.

Btw. using session cookies like `Cookie: JSESSIONID=41D1CCDF94D3150F0FCA3754E347A4AD` [is not RESTful](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/215759/65755).

I know very little about java request mapping, but by REST you use `POST` usually to add a new item resource to a collection resource, for example `POST /rights` in your case, and `PUT` usually to edit an entire item resource, for example `PUT /rights/{id}` where `{id}` should be a unique resource id (probably the same as one of your aggregate ids). In your code I can't see anything related to this URL structure by the PUT request. You may be interested [in PATCH](http://jasonsirota.com/rest-partial-updates-use-post-put-or-patch) as well.