# Unable to send file data to nodejs server from client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, file-upload

i am creating simple file upload module in Angular js(v1.3.4). I am using Nodejs server side. 
I am using https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload library. It looks pretty straight forward but i am stuck at the basic step.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="FileUploadController">   
        <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>  
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {

                for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
                    var file = $files[i];
                    $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/file-transfer/123/upload', 

                       // headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                       //     withCredentials: true,
                       //     transformRequest: angular.identity,
                       file: file       
                    }).progress(function(evt) {
                            console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            // file is uploaded successfully
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                }
```

On Server side, I am using `multer` for multipart . 
client is sending the request to server but not sending the file data.

```
app.all('/file-transfer/:id/upload', function (req, res) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    console.log(req.body);     // prints - {}
    console.log(req.files);   // prints -  {}
});
```

**Request Header** -

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Me...    POST
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:8080
Origin  http://localhost
Pragma  no-cache
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
```

I used the same code as in example of repository.Maybe i am missing something.

**Note** - Server codes working fine when i use simple html 5 form without angular or if i use $http.post.

**EDIT** : It was CORS problem, Read the comments of answer.

Comment: Maybe you need preflight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest

Comment: @Paul hey , I just used res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', \'http://localhost'\);  Not working , I dont think CORS is an issue.  When i send request with $http.post. It works. Problem is in implementation.

Comment: there's a very specific list of what you can send or request over CORS without having handler code for preflight/OPTIONS requests in the server.  For example, text is OK but application/json is not, even though it is also basically text. I'm wondering if the bare browser uses those, and then when you add angular, it gets changed in angular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using same library, the only thing different in my client side code is I have the `method: 'POST'` header being sent:

```
            $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                url: '/api/uploads', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
                // method: 'POST' or 'PUT',
                method: 'POST',
                // headers: {'header-key': 'header-value'},
                // withCredentials: true,
                data: { type: 'profileImage' },
                file: file//, // or list of files: $files for html5 only
                // fileName: 'doc.jpg' or ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', ...] // to modify the name of the file
                /* customize file formData name ('Content-Desposition'), server side file variable name.
                 Default is 'file' */
                //fileFormDataName: myFile, //or a list of names for multiple files (html5).
                /* customize how data is added to formData. See #40#issuecomment-28612000 for sample code */
                //formDataAppender: function(formData, key, val){}
            }).progress(function (e) {
                console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * e.loaded / e.total));
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                console.log(data);
                $scope.user.profileImages = data;
                $rootScope.$emit('message', { text: "Your profile image has been updated." });
            }).error(function(data){
                if ( data.error === 'UnsupportedFiletype' ) {
                    $rootScope.$emit('message', { type: 'error', text: "Woops, we don't support that filetype." });
                }
            });
```

Edit: The solution was to just properly serve a cors header:

`npm install cors` and `app.use(cors())`.

Comment: Hey , on which platform you are posting the request server side. because if i use the same code and post the request in .php file , It is printing the $_FILES(able to access the data) . But if i use the nodejs server , I am unable to catch the file data. One more thing ,if i send file data using $http.post on nodejs server. It works fine.That means server is working fine. but this client side code is working fine on .php file . I am not able to catch the error.

Comment: I also change the header of server like this 
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

Comment: `npm install cors` and `app.use(cors())` will make it less ugly.

Comment: also try `file = req.files.file` to get the file you uploaded.

Comment: wooo , cors module did the trick. very well.It was cross domain problem.I will tick this.

Comment: fyi, you aren't whitelisting. anyone can use your api :) you were writing out the allowed domain that the request was being sent from. If you're going to do that just use `*`.