# Can not post data via ajax to web2py rest api - possible CORS issue

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, cors, web2py

I've searched for answers to this issue for nearly two weeks. I have a simple system built in web2py. Note: I'm not exactly a python veteran. I am attempting to use the web2py rest api to post data to the database.  If I run the curl command, the database table is updated and the rest returns the id of the newly added row. This is the desired outcome.  However, if I attempt to use an ajax request to perform the same action, the request runs successful but the rest returns an empty object and the database is not updated. I've added a CORS wrapper class which allows me to get past the cross-origin issue; but I'm not sure if this is at the same time preventing the database from updating etc. I'm stomped.  Also note that I formatted the data (in the ajax call) as a json object as well, but still nothing.  Please find all the code below.

**MOST IMPORTANT:** I am receiving the following message - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any/All help is greatly appreciated guys. Thanks :)

```
#Web2py model
db.define_table(‘myboard',
#Field('userid','reference auth_user'),
    Field('userid',db.auth_user,default=auth.user_id),
Field('title',requires=IS_LENGTH(100,1),label=“Board Title"),
Field(‘idea_a',requires=IS_LENGTH(75,1),label=“Idea A"),
Field(‘idea_b',requires=IS_LENGTH(75,1),label=“Idea B"),
Field('description','text',requires=IS_LENGTH(250,1),label=“Board Description"),
Field('contributors','integer',default='0'),
    Field('status','integer',writable=False,readable=False,default='1'), #1=draft, 2=public
Field('created_on','datetime',writable=False,default=request.now))


#Web2py controllers
def CORS(f):
"""
Enables CORS for any action
"""
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): #*args, **kwargs
    if request.env.http_origin:
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.env.http_origin
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true";
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Authorization,Content-Type,data";
        return dict()
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
return wrapper


auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True
@CORS
@request.restful()
def api():
from gluon.serializers import json
response.view = 'generic.'+request.extension
def GET(*args,**vars):
    patterns = 'auto'
    parser = db.parse_as_rest(patterns,args,vars)
    if parser.status == 200:
        return dict(content=parser.response)
    else:
        raise HTTP(parser.status,parser.error)
def POST(table_name,**vars):
    return json(db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars))
    return dict()
def PUT(table_name,record_id,**vars):
    return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).update(**vars)
def DELETE(table_name,record_id):
    return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).delete()
return dict(GET=GET, PUT=PUT, POST=POST,  DELETE=DELETE)


//CURL COMMAND - This Works!

curl -i --user somename@gmail.com:thepassword -H Accept:application/json -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/cc/default/api/myboard.json -H Content-Type: application/json -d 'userid=2&title=THE_TITLE&description=THE_DESCRIP&idea_a=THE 1st idea&idea_b=THE 2nd idea’


//AJAX CALL - Doesn't Work :(

var userid = 2;
var title = "THE_TITLE_HERE";
var description = "THE_DESCRIPTION_HERE"
var idea_a = "THE 1st idea";
var idea_b = "THE 2nd idea";


var userID = ’somename@gmail.com';
var password = ’thepassword';

var theData = "userid=2&title="+title+"&description="+description+”&idea_a=“+ideaA+”&idea_b=“+ideaB;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(userID + ":" + password)},
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cc/default/api/myboard.json",
    contentType:  "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: theData,
    success: function (data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        alert(textStatus);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

The database table does not update but the request runs successfully. It returns an empty object each time.. {}

Answer (score 0):

Your `wrapper` function calls `return dict()`, which executes before the call to `f()`, so the decorated `api` function never gets called. Just remove that line.

Also, note that depending on the nature of the Ajax request, the browser might first make a [preflight request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30296149/440323). So, your decorator code will need to detect and respond to such requests with the [appropriate headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689332/440323).

Comment: Hey Anthony, thanks a bunch. I commented out the  return dict() line of code and now I'm getting the following error...                                XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/cc/default/api/myboard.json. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Comment: Two other points: 1. After commenting out the following decorators @auth.requires_login()  AND @request.restful()  as well as changing the response.view  to 'generic.'+request.extension  ajax request ran successfully (code 200) but the data was not inserted into the database:    2 and the return message was html script from the api page. Very strange

Comment: I updated the answer. Also, note that you cannot remove the `@request.restful` decorator, as it is required in order for web2py to convert the call to `api()` into a call to the embedded `POST()` function.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. That makes total sense.  So after uncommenting the @request.restful decorator I received the following 'preflight' message:   "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405."   It is like the CORS decorator doesn't even exist now.

Comment: I'm also getting a 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED message. The method that the network is showing is OPTIONS

Comment: What web server are you using? Also, please show your updated CORS decorator code (i.e., including the preflight check and response).

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks the help. I solved the issue. Your guidance was super useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this issue by doing three things.
1. I removed the CORS decorator code from the controller file - default.py
2. I inserted the below code at the top of the default.py controller file

```
if request.env.http_origin:
     response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.env.http_origin;
     response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "POST,GET,OPTIONS";
     response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true";
     response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Accept-Encoding";
```

3. I modified the api class to include the OPTIONS verb by adding the following at the bottom of the class, after the DELETE verb. The modified api class is as follows.. **Note:** The change is in the last 4 lines of code.

   ```
    def api():
    from gluon.serializers import json
    response.view = 'generic.'+request.extension
    def GET(*args,**vars):
         patterns = 'auto'
         parser = db.parse_as_rest(patterns,args,vars)
         if parser.status == 200:
            return dict(content=parser.response)
         else:
            raise HTTP(parser.status,parser.error)
    def POST(table_name,**vars):
        #return db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars)
        #data = gluon.contrib.simplejson.loads(request.body.read())
        return json(db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars))
        return dict()
    def PUT(table_name,record_id,**vars):
        return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).update(**vars)
    def DELETE(table_name,record_id):
        return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).delete()
    def OPTIONS(*args,**vars):
        print "OPTION called"
        return True
    return dict(GET=GET,POST=POST,PUT=PUT,DELETE=DELETE,OPTIONS=OPTIONS)
   ```

And that's it.  The issue was with web2py in that I needed to include the OPTIONS verb in the api call AND including the code for the headers directly at the top of the controller file instead of putting it in a wrapper seemed to work for me. Now everything connects and the database is updated.

reference url: https://github.com/OpenTreeOfLife/phylesystem-api/issues/26