# Why ajax post can not load page when use short url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

Why ajax post can not load page when use short url ?

When i use short URL `test.php` in ajax post like this

```
<script>
function send_username_value_for_check_available() {
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#username_send_value_fid').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#mySpan_username').show();
                    $('#mySpan_username').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
}
</script>
```

i will get error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/test.php. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

But when i use full URL `https://www.example.com/test.php` it's work good.

How can i do for use short URL in ajax post ?

Comment: `preflight` - makes it look cross origin ... how odd

Comment: can i manage this issue with .htaccess

Comment: Does the page `./test.php` is redirecting to some other page  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your short URL `test.php` resolves to `example.com/test.php`
`example.com` and `www.example.com` are seen as different domains. So the ajax request is treated like a cross-domain call.
Try authorizing `example.com` and/or `www.example.com` in your script with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (you should avoid allowing '*'). Using php:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com");
```

For further information:
- "CORS response headers" might be search-keywords to help you on this subject.
- Also have a look a this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689332/3872061

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do nothing with AJAX with short URK issue...

You have to allow CORS from your server for this Domain and it will work

http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html