# Issue with reading Response headers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors, same-origin-policy

I am trying to build a chrome extension for which i need to ping to different machines.The code which i tried with is able to read the response headers for a https site but not for http.I am new to Javascripting. Any help would be great.I understand it is a CORS issue and tried setting the headers in the client code.many forums mention it setting al the server side but where can I do in this case? Please find the code below and the plugin UI and response returned from https site in the snapshot.

[image]

Code--

```
url="https://www.icicibank.com/";
//url = "www.rediff.com/";  
ping = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
ping.open("get", url,true);
//ping.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"); 
// ping.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
ping.send(null)
ping.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (ping.readyState==4) {
alert(ping.getAllResponseHeaders());
//alertify.alert(ping.getAllResponseHeaders());
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to handle [preflight requests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8689332/4361743) on the target server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is indeed part of the server response, **not** the request. So you cannot "set" it on your side.

However, extensions are allowed to bypass CORS restrictions and [make cross-origin requests](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr). But for that you need to list domains you're going to connect to [in manifest permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission). The user will be warned, at install time, that you'll interact with those domains.

For example, to allow requests to `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` domains regardless of CORS, you need to include in the manifest:

```
"permissions" : [
  "*://example.com/"
],
```

If you can't say which sites you'll need to connect to in advance, you'll either need permissions for all urls (special permission, literally, `"<all_urls>"`) or use [Optional Permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) to request that at runtime.

Comment: Wow.. thanks Xan for your help. I had already set "<all_urls>" in the manifest under permissions but it was not working but setting it under Optional permissions worked for me and that too without any warning.Many thanks !!!

Comment: Traditional permissions override optional permissions. Once granted, your LOCAL install will have them granted - it will work on your install, but stop working if you remove and add the extension again.

Comment: what i have done Xan is having the "<all_urls>" defined in both the permissions and optional permissions. Even if i remove and add the extension, it is working fine.

Comment: But you don't need it in optional permissions for it to work. You really, really don't. You probably just forgot to reload.