# CakePHP2: CORS Preflight issues with JWT Auth

Tags: php, angularjs, http, cakephp, cors

I'm building an Ionic 1 app that talks to a REST API implemented in CakePHP 2.8, using [JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) for auth.

In an unauthorized state, my app is able to make GET / POST requests to the server with no issue. However, once I have authenticated and my app is sending a `authToken` header along with every request, Angular automatically sends an `OPTIONS` preflight request first.

This is where the problem starts. Because the automatic preflight request does not have the `authToken` header set, and because the API endpoint requires authorization, CakePHP responds with a 302 FOUND redirect to `/login`. The app (or browser, at this testing phase) considers this unsafe, and never goes on to make the proper request.

**My question:** How can I get CakePHP to respond appropriately to preflight OPTIONS requests so that AngularJS knows it can safely send a custom header to a cross-domain server?

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest), this is what needs to happen:

Request headers:

```
Origin: http://yourdomain.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Custom-Header
```

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com // Same as origin above
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header
```

**Things I've tried:**

-Setting `.htaccess` to always respond to `OPTIONS` requests with a `200`. I get a 200 response, but the response says "your server is misconfigured" and, because it doesn't have the proper headers set, the real `$http` request never goes through.

-Getting CakePHP to always respond a certain way to `OPTIONS` requests. The issue here is getting Cake to skip authorization, skip trying to run the controller action, and send back a HTTP 200 response with the proper headers set.

```
    // AppController::beforeFilter();
    if($this->request->is("options")){
        // Send the appropriate response based on the request
    }
```

For the curious, here are the headers that get exchanged in the course of a failed `$http` request:

```
GENERAL:
Request URL:https://api.example.com/rest_users/profile.json
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:x.x.x.x:443

REQUEST HEADERS:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authtoken
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:api.example.com
Origin:http://x.x.x.x:8100
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://x.x.x.x:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36


RESPONSE HEADERS:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, x-xsrf-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:172800
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 29 Dec 2016 18:51:30 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=99
Location:https://api.example.com/login
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3
```

Comment: First: You should probably use the more common `Authorization` header instead of your custom `authtoken` header. Second: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, x-xsrf-token`... I am not seeing that you are allowed to send your custom `authtoken` header; it's not in the allowed list. That is probably the issue.

Comment: I would still need to have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: x.x.x.x` (generally an IP address) header set in the response, though. And it can't be a wildcard. The header needs to be customized because the requests are going to be sent from an app.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not typically an IP address, it's usually domain names... unless you are accessing your site via IP (in the URL bar) it will be fully qualified domain names. `*` works fine for testing, you would want to lock it down later. But that is neither here nor there... not sure why you brought it up... I was talking about Access-Control-Allow-**Headers** which currently does not allow you to send `authtoken` header and will block your request as it is not allowed by your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that allows CakePHP to handle CORS preflights correctly. It sets the headers, sends the response, and shuts down Cake before the requested action can run.

Be sure to have `parent::beforeFilter();` in all your controllers so that this code runs.

In AppController::beforeFilter():

```
    if($this->request->is("options")){
        // Set the headers
        $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
        $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*');
        $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Authorization');
        // Send the response
        $this->response->send();
        // Don't do anything else!
        $this->_stop();
    }
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at [**dispatcher filters**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html) and  [**`CakeResponse::cors()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-CakeResponse.html#_cors).