# Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response error while set request header

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the below code in my ajax request.

```
  beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer t-7614f875-8423-4f20-a674-d7cf3096290e') }
```

1. Initially, i need to know the purpose of xhr.setRequestHeader().
2. while set like above , i receive the console error as

   Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I searched a lot and so many solutions found, but i didn't understand.

Any one please explain, why we are using this and why this issue occurs and how to resolve this.

Need the easy understanding about this issue, please suggest

Comment: *I think* you have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers = true` in your headers sent from the server to allow setting headers on requests on the client.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers = true, was added in backend or client side?
How to add this ?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine `.setRequestHeaders()` is from an old version of JQuery. It's not in the current docs. This would be a similar function:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

For your error,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS

> In CORS, a preflight request with the OPTIONS method is sent, so that the server can respond whether it is acceptable to send the request with these parameters. The Access-Control-Request-Method header notifies the server as part of a preflight request that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a POST request method. The Access-Control-Request-Headers header notifies the server that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a X-PINGOTHER and Content-Type custom headers.  The server now has an opportunity to determine whether it wishes to accept a request under these circumstances.

Basically it is a browser security feature to ask the server if it is OK to send your headers. If `Authorization` is not part of the list of acceptable headers, then the browser will give an error. It is a bug on the server side. I ran into this problem because I used `Authentication` header instead.

You have to use your own server to access the URL and bypass the browser security restrictions.