# need to make a cors request from localhost - standard solutions don't seem to work as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to make a CORS request from localhost. I have the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin Chrome plugin installed and turned on and when I hover over the menu item it shows: "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *". I created a .bat file with the following contents:

```
start chrome http://localhost:8080/MyPage.html --disable-web-security --user-data-di
```

This opens a new Chrome instance at the expected url but the CORS request still fails with the following error:

```
Failed to load [rest-url]: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can you recommend any workarounds for this?

Comment: Is this just for debugging? Also is the remote HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I'm calling an API to a trading platform. The remote is https.  I was planning on making API calls from localhost on my local machine since I'll be the only user.  I'm using http-server npm package to host an html page on my local filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

could you show the code  and give us some more information about the technology etc. which you are using?

It seems like you´re not sending a "preflight"-Request, your preflight-request does not contain the needed headers or your remote does not return the right headers:

For example, suppose the browser makes a request with the following headers:

```
Origin: http://yourdomain.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Custom-Header
```

Your server should then respond with the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header
```

> Credits to: @monsur

See also: [CORS - How do 'preflight' an httprequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest?rq=1)

the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` needs to contain all custom headers your sending allong with the real request, it will fail if not. At least for me, the error messages are somewhat cryptic and don´t always point in the right direction.