# 403 (CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.) [VueJs]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using an HTTP request to upload an image to the Azure storage, It's work for me when the CORS of the storage account is general, for example:

```
allowed origins: *
allowed methods: 7 selected (which all options)
allowed headers: *
exposed headers: *
max age: 0
```

And in my Http request (sing axios):

```
headers: {
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
     "Content-Type": "image/png",
     "x-ms-date": currentDate,
     "x-ms-version": ""2017-11-09"",
     "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
}
```

It's work with me and image uploaded, but when I modified the CORS to add some constraints, it does not work. for example:

```
allowed origins: https://XXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/
allowed methods: 7 selected (which all options)
allowed headers: Authorization,x-ms-*
exposed headers: x-ms-meta-*
max age: 3600
```

And in my HTTP request (sing axios):

```
headers: {
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "https://XXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PUT,GET,PATCH,POST,HEAD,DELETE,MERGE,OPTIONS",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Authorization,x-ms-*,content-*",
     "Content-Type": "image/png",
     "x-ms-date": currentDate,
     "x-ms-version": ""2017-11-09"",
     "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
}
```

I faced two Error messages:

> OPTIONS
>   https://XXXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/user-avatar/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>   403 (CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.)
>
> Failed to load
>   https://XXXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/user-avatar/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

How should I solve the problem?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header

Comment: adding random headers (like response headers into a request) will trigger CORS preflight - and if your server doesn't expect preflight (OPTIONS request) then you'll definitely get issues

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "https://XXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/",
```

to

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "localhost:8080/",
```

Have a look  [CORS - How do 'preflight' an httprequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest)

Comment: umm, what this answer suppose op do? especially if the server is on blob.core.windows.net?

Comment: @BagusTesa The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` refers to the **clients** allowed to connect. OP's error message indicates they are connecting from `localhost:8080`

Comment: It doesn't matter what the server is. The client server matters here. So, if one is making a request from localhost:8080, he should add this to access-control.

Comment: oh i see, i did not saw that `localhost:8080`. at a glance i only saw op says request.

Comment: @learner do I need to add this also in Azure CORS?