# CORS/Preflight error with WorldPay AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm picking up on someone else work with a custom template, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to load https://api.worldpay.com/v1/orders: Response to the preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is the code that sends the AJAX request:

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.worldpay.com/v1/orders",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              "Authorization": worldPayServiceKey
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(options),
            success: function (response){
              if (response.paymentStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
                current_booking.payment = obj.response;
              } else {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem with your payment. We will send you an invoice instead.");
              }

              makeBooking();
            }
          });
```

I've had a similar problem with CORS before, but I haven't seen the preflight error before. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS - How do 'preflight' an httprequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest)

Answer (score 0):

please remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from request header. that is a server side header.

Then add Content-Type as,

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,`multipart/form-data` or `text/plain` depending on what you are sending with the request. for example,

```
headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "Authorization": worldPayServiceKey
            },
```

> The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:

```
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data 
> - text/plain
```

for more info, read the [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Hope It helps. good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix the error I'm getting - Failed to load https://api.worldpay.com/v1/orders: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{IPADDRESSHERE}' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I just check the apo docs, according to  doc  Content type shoud be application/json. try adding "Content-type: application/json". It shoud work.