# How to fix "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:51255/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: cors, rxjs, angular6, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I try to communicate between dotnet webapi project and angular6 project.

Scenario: when I enter loginname and password and click login button, it should fetch access_token, username from server and display the result in displayresult.html.
I Know this question is asked previously, but even after trying with all those 
solutions, I could not communicate my angular6 project with dotnetwebapi.

To fix CORS policy, I did some of the changes in my dotnetwebapi project.

1. Added `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` in  `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` of `startup.auth.cs`.
2. In `web.config`, added custom headers, please see the code below.

authservice.ts

```
export class AuthService
{
private TokenAPI="http://localhost:51255/token";
    login(username:string,password:string):Observable<TokenParams>
    {
        var headersfortokenapi = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-encoded'});
        var data="grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

        return this.objhttp.post(this.TokenAPI,data,{ headers:headersfortokenapi})
        .pipe(
            map(res=>res.json()
             )
            );      
    }
}
```

Login.component.ts

```
 OnLoginClick()  
{   
this.objauthservice.login(this.username,this.password)
.subscribe
(
 data=>
  {
    this.tokenparam=data;
   this.objauthservice.AccessToken=this.tokenparam.access_token;
    this.objroute.navigate(['/Displayproducts']);
  }
) 
 }
```

When I click login button in login page, it goes to the above method and it calls authservice login method.
Now i have created `TOKENWEBAPIPROJECT` dotnet project.
This project is running in `http://localhost:51255/token`.
The code snippet where I did some changes in `TOKENWEBAPIPROJECT`.

startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
//it has the default code for connecting to dbcontext and application
 app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
}
```

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS,token"/>
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, application/x-www-form-encoded, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

I tested the post request of `http://localhost:51255/token` in Postman.
Here I send username, password, grant_type=password and it returns me correct access_token, username, token_type etc.

Expected: when I enter loginname and password and click login button, it should fetch access_token, username from server and display the result in `displayresult.html`.

Actual: Instead I am getting the following Errors:-
1. `OPTIONS http://localhost:51255/token 400 (Bad Request)`

2. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:51255/token' 
   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Comment: can you try to update your <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin">  value to "*" ?

Comment: yes i tried , then also same error happens.

Comment: I think you also have to allow the header `X-Requested-With` in your webapi backend.

Answer (score 0):

The port number must be identical in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response and in the `Origin` request.

Reference:

> Web applications that are not uniquely identified by specific host names, and/or mapped to specific ports, do not necessarily have a unique origin, and thus will not be able to securely utilize the mechanism defined in this specification. This is because an **origin is composed of only the scheme, hostname, and port**.

https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Please also see answers for managing the preflight request:

[CORS - How do 'preflight' an httprequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest?rq=1)

You must send status code `200` in response to the `OPTIONS` preflight-request.

Comment: Dotnet Webapi URL: 'http://localhost:51255/token' and Angular project URL: http://localhost:4200 .How the Port number can be identical, both are different technology. Can you pls tell me which port should I give in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: The requested resource must allow the requesting resource to be requested. If your request goes from 4200 to 51255 you must allow 4200 on 51255. The error message you have is clear about which part is expected in which response.

Comment: yes, for that only I have added access-control-allow-origin in web.config as http://localhost:4200 and also EnableCors in my DotnetWebAPI project. Whether my configuration is correct in DotnetWebAPI project?